# filtered objects image does not display in template page?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

When i get all object of a class in django, it did worked but when i used filter to get spesific object, returned 404 error while getting the image?

**Model of class:**

```
    baslik = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    aciklama = models.TextField()
    kategori = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=category_choices, default="Yol ve Köprü İnşaatı")
    referans_fotografi = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="media/reference_images/")
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

**View page:**

```
def reference(request, *args, **kwargs):
    the_value = "Yol ve Köprü İnşaatı"
    reference_category = Reffrences.objects.filter(kategori=the_value)
    print(reference_category)
```

**template page:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Referanslar {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    
{% include "navbar.html" with title_pager="Referanslar" %}

    <div class="container my-5">
        {%for x in reference_category%}
        <img src="{{ x.referans_fotografi }}"/>
        <div>{{x.referans_fotografi}}</div>
        {%endfor%}
```

[this is what i see at my page when i expect to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCUIh.png)